# C++ Program crashes on passing object by value

Tags: c++, oop

Error occurs when I pass another object to a function -> `a.Concat(b);`

I have just reverted to C++ from Java for a project. When I pass object by value in this code, then an error occurs. Almost every time it is displaying a different error message, sometimes bad alloc, sometimes displaying half the output. I tried passing by reference and also made a copy constructor but both attempts failed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

    class NFA
{
    public:
        NFA(string);
        NFA(vector<vector<string> >);
        NFA Concat(NFA other_nfa);
        NFA Union(NFA);
        NFA KleeneStar();
        void display();
        int GetNFASize(){ return ALPHABET_SIZE; }
        int getNoOfStates(){ return NO_OF_STATES; }

        vector<vector<string> > table;
        int ALPHABET_SIZE;
        int NO_OF_STATES;
    private:
};

NFA::NFA(string input)
{
    table.resize(2);
    NO_OF_STATES = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);
    }
    table[0][0] = "2";
    table[0][1] = input;
    table[1][0] = "3";

    ALPHABET_SIZE = 3;
}

void NFA::display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; j++)
        {
            cout << table[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

NFA NFA::Concat(NFA other_nfa)
{
    vector<vector<string> > ans_vector;
    ans_vector.resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + other_nfa.ALPHABET_SIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; j++)
        {
            ans_vector[i][j] = table[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = other_nfa.NO_OF_STATES - 1; i < other_nfa.NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < other_nfa.ALPHABET_SIZE; j++)
        {
            ans_vector[i][j] = other_nfa.table[i][j];
        }
    }
    ans_vector[NO_OF_STATES - 1][3] = other_nfa.table[0][0];
    NFA ansNFA(ans_vector);
}

NFA::NFA(vector<vector<string> >)
{

}

int main()
{
        NFA a("a");
        a.display();

        NFA b("b");
        b.display();

        NFA ab = a.Concat(b);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a bad habit to call variables all uppercase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
NFA::NFA(string input)
{
    table.resize(2);
    NO_OF_STATES = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);
    }
    table[0][0] = "2";
    table[0][1] = input;
    table[1][0] = "3";

    ALPHABET_SIZE = 3;
}
```

You variable initializations are out of order.  When you use

```
table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);
```

`ALPHABET_SIZE` contains garbage as you have not set a value yet.  Just move `ALPHABET_SIZE = 3;` before the for loop and you should be okay.

I would also suggest you use a member initialization list for all variables to you can.  In this case your constructor would look like

```
NFA::NFA(string input) : NO_OF_STATES(2), ALPHABET_SIZE(3)
{
    table.resize(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);
    }
    table[0][0] = "2";
    table[0][1] = input;
    table[1][0] = "3";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You resize a `vector<vector<string>` but fail to resize any of the contained `vector`s:

```
ans_vector.resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + other_nfa.ALPHABET_SIZE);
```

And then later you index into the nested vectors, which goes out of bounds:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; j++)
    {
        ans_vector[i][j] = table[i][j];
    }
}
```

You'll need to call `resize` for every `vector` inside `ans_vector`, or use `push_back`, `emplace_back` etc, which would probably be safer for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But actually, the program is crashing because of some other reason because even when I remove the whole body of the Concat(NFA) function, the program still crashes.

Comment: @MustehssunIqbal: Yeah, looks like NathanOliver found another issue. However that doesn't mean what I've pointed out wouldn't cause issues; you need to address that, too.

Comment: Yep.  This is a another issue and will also burn you.

Answer (score 1):

AlPHABET_SIZE is not defined  in:

> table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);

by default, it contains some garbage value. This might be your problem.

```
NFA::NFA(string input)
{
    table.resize(2);
    NO_OF_STATES = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_STATES; i++)
    {
        table[i].resize(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);
    }
    table[0][0] = "2";
    table[0][1] = input;
    table[1][0] = "3";

    ALPHABET_SIZE = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ALPHABET_SIZE is being used in the ctor of NFA though it was not initialized. it causes weird behaviour.

You are creating three objects a,b,ab. during construction of the object program crashes. it has nothing to do with pass by reference/value or using copy ctor.

Answer (score 1):

From the first look I would say the problem lays in the vector-access of `table`, which would go out-of-range.

From design-point, several issues:

- It seems you `_other_nfa` can be declared const reference:

  `NFA NFA::Concat(const NFA& other_nfa)`
- There is no return. At the end of your Concat method there should be sth. like:

  `return ansNFA;`
- It seems within Concat you don't change your member variables like `table` (which btw. is no good name for a member-variable). If Concat dosn't change the class members, you should declare it const:

  NFA NFA::Concat(const NFA& other_nfa) *const*

Comment: That return statement is a mistake. I removed it while trying to find out the error. Got your point about constant reference. +1